# Hyperledger fabric peers consistently logging peer changed its PKI-ID logs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have hyperledger fabric peers running on version 2.3.2 and the peer's certificates are renewed. The peers continuously logging with message `peer2.xorg:7051 changed its PKI-ID from xxxxxx to xxxxxxx` and then `purging xxxxxxxx from membership`

Does anyone knows the reason for these continuos logs?

Below are the complete logs:

```
2022-06-14 08:47:42.647 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10d08 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.peer_address=10.20.30.140:38550 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer2.org1.com,OU=peer,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=24.617863135s
2022-06-14 08:47:42.647 UTC [gossip.discovery] purge -> INFO 10d09 Purging e3c96c537b91675f3a6428a509a287addb65bddeeacb4b5d000b6e4ef567b013 from membership
2022-06-14 08:47:42.647 UTC [gossip.comm] createConnection -> INFO 10d0a Peer peer2.org1.com:7051 changed its PKI-ID from 1c56c0d7a0397dd9c756205197067ef26bef156cdf5ee27af16728a62123fb76 to 9994c9e8d63ae1f6564d1713f9a5393c458a78dfdb915ea2a4a4f6efb6d26dae
2022-06-14 08:47:42.647 UTC [gossip.discovery] purge -> INFO 10d0b Purging 1c56c0d7a0397dd9c756205197067ef26bef156cdf5ee27af16728a62123fb76 from membership
2022-06-14 08:47:42.648 UTC [gossip.comm] createConnection -> INFO 10d0c Peer peer2.org1.com:7051 changed its PKI-ID from da99b167b6c3a7b8289dd943568a382ac0f27d2d0ffcee53725f4fd18a10be9c to 9994c9e8d63ae1f6564d1713f9a5393c458a78dfdb915ea2a4a4f6efb6d26dae
2022-06-14 08:47:42.648 UTC [gossip.discovery] purge -> INFO 10d0d Purging da99b167b6c3a7b8289dd943568a382ac0f27d2d0ffcee53725f4fd18a10be9c from membership
2022-06-14 08:47:42.649 UTC [gossip.comm] createConnection -> INFO 10d0e Peer peer2.org1.com:7051 changed its PKI-ID from 87b299aa1d0a71002dbbac8b0b1bf049a6bd1aa58e669d31f0355587af15a8e9 to 9994c9e8d63ae1f6564d1713f9a5393c458a78dfdb915ea2a4a4f6efb6d26dae
2022-06-14 08:47:42.649 UTC [gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN 10d0f peer2.org1.com:7051, PKIid:87b299aa1d0a71002dbbac8b0b1bf049a6bd1aa58e669d31f0355587af15a8e9 isn't responsive: EOF

2022-06-14 08:47:42.649 UTC [gossip.discovery] purge -> INFO 10d10 Purging 87b299aa1d0a71002dbbac8b0b1bf049a6bd1aa58e669d31f0355587af15a8e9 from membership

2022-06-14 08:47:42.657 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10d11 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.peer_address=10.20.30.140:38546 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer2.org1-shared.com,OU=peer,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US" error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=24.712078411s

2022-06-14 08:47:42.659 UTC [gossip.comm] createConnection -> INFO 10d12 Peer peer2.org1-shared.com:7051 changed its PKI-ID from 5f03f639eb1bc912609b9208a2577cb8575c20a103d71155efe68487dedde236 to 99d3b90022039ca4d3311c96b1ccddc64e58d170f15e39cc18232e43be1c7b63

2022-06-14 08:47:42.659 UTC [gossip.discovery] purge -> INFO 10d13 Purging 5f03f639eb1bc912609b9208a2577cb8575c20a103d71155efe68487dedde236 from membership
2022-06-14 08:47:42.659 UTC [gossip.comm] createConnection -> INFO 10d14 Peer peer2.org1-shared.com:7051 changed its PKI-ID from d4b6c5c8659587ea44ac4ba1f813dc3e52194ca0c2e09b7ecfe1cbd47d1db7c4 to 99d3b90022039ca4d3311c96b1ccddc64e58d170f15e39cc18232e43be1c7b63


2022-06-14 08:47:42.660 UTC [gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN 10d15 peer2.org1-shared.com:7051, PKIid:d4b6c5c8659587ea44ac4ba1f813dc3e52194ca0c2e09b7ecfe1cbd47d1db7c4 isn't responsive: EOF

2022-06-14 08:47:42.660 UTC [gossip.discovery] purge -> INFO 10d16 Purging d4b6c5c8659587ea44ac4ba1f813dc3e52194ca0c2e09b7ecfe1cbd47d1db7c4 from membership


2022-06-14 08:47:42.675 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10d17 unary call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=Ping grpc.request_deadline=2022-06-14T08:47:44.674Z grpc.peer_address=10.20.30.140:39676 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer2.org1.com,OU=peer,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=62.13µs
2022-06-14 08:47:42.710 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 10d18 finished chaincode: assets duration: 37ms channel=assetschannel txID=58a9628e
2022-06-14 08:47:42.711 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10d19 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.20.30.140:34366 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=39.919313ms
2022-06-14 08:47:43.034 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 10d1a finished chaincode: assets duration: 35ms channel=assetschannel txID=010913f5
2022-06-14 08:47:43.035 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10d1b unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.20.30.140:34366 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=38.114437ms
2022-06-14 08:47:43.153 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 10d1c finished chaincode: assets duration: 49ms channel=assetschannel txID=49d4c88f
2022-06-14 08:47:43.153 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10d1d unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.20.30.140:34366 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=52.987518ms
2022-06-14 08:47:43.279 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 10d1e finished chaincode: assets duration: 85ms channel=assetschannel txID=69279b3e
```

It keeps on purging same PKI ID again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to some experts, I got to know that peers might be fetching service discovery cache from other peers. This is why the errors were not being resolved even after restarting a peer.

After restarting all the peers at the same time, the issue was resolved.

Thanks to Yacov Manevich

Comment: I am facing same issue using Hyperledger fabric v2.4.7
The above provided solution seems like a temporary patch. It would not be feasible to restart all the peers of network in a large network. Is there a logical fix for this issue?